# Want to remove row onclick

Tags: javascript

Hi I am new to Javascript (actually i work on php mysql).  I want to remove few dynamically generated rows . I want to pass element id to function and then remove from there. But id's are created dynamically.
Below code has variable for number of rows to show, and a button in front of each row , onclick of button the two input elements in that row, should be removed.

```
    <script>
        function removeMore()
        {
            var elem = document.getElementById();
            elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        $row=5;
        for($i=1; $i< $row; $i++)
        {
            $img_id= "img_".$i;
            $cap_id= "cap_".$i;
            $row_id= $i*100;
            ?>
                <table>
                    <tr id="<?php echo $row_id;?>">
                        <td>
                            <input type="file" name="img[]" id="<?php echo $img_id;?>" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="cap[]" id="<?php echo $cap_id;?>" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" name="rem_but" id="<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" onclick="removeMore(document.getElementsByName('rem_but')[0].value)" /> 
                            <!-- or may be something like this.value to get value of id. -->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <?php   
        }
    ?>
```

I simply want to delete the row whose button is clicked

HTML looks like this

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
function removeMore(eid){
document.write(eid);
var xd= eid*100;
 var elem = document.getElementById(xd);
 elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
 return false;
 }
 </script>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<tr id="100"><td><input type="file" name="img[]" id="img_1" /></td><td><input  type="text" name="cap[]" id="cap_1" /></td><td><input type="button" name="rem_but" id="1"  value="1" onclick="removeMore(document.getElementsById(this.value)" />
</td></tr>
 </table>
 <table>
 <tr id="200"><td><input type="file" name="img[]" id="img_2" /></td><td><input type="text" name="cap[]" id="cap_2" /></td><td><input type="button" name="rem_but" id="2" value="2" onclick="removeMore(document.getElementsById(this.value)" />
 </td></tr>
 </table>
 <table>
 <tr id="300"><td><input type="file" name="img[]" id="img_3" /></td><td><input type="text" name="cap[]" id="cap_3" /></td><td><input type="button" name="rem_but" id="3" value="3" onclick="removeMore(document.getElementsById(this.value)" />
 </td></tr>
 </table>
 <table>
 <tr id="400"><td><input type="file" name="img[]" id="img_4" /></td><td><input type="text" name="cap[]" id="cap_4" /></td><td><input type="button" name="rem_but" id="4" value="4" onclick="removeMore(document.getElementsById(this.value)" />
 </td></tr>
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I haven't got the energy to do the PHP processing in my head. Can you post the rendered HTML, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>    
<script>
    // pass the ID into the method.
    function removeMore(id)
    {
        var elem = document.getElementById(id); // getElementById requires the ID
        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
        return false;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $row=5;
        for($i=1; $i< $row; $i++)
        {
            $img_id= "img_".$i;
            $cap_id= "cap_".$i;
            $row_id= $i*100;
            ?>
                <table>
                    <tr id="<?php echo $row_id;?>">
                        <td>
                            <input type="file" name="img[]" id="<?php echo $img_id;?>" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="cap[]" id="<?php echo $cap_id;?>" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" name="rem_but" id="<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" onclick="removeMore(<?php echo $row_id;?>)" /> 
                            <!-- You're using PHP - just print the ID in the right place. -->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <?php   
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Gareth . I was not knowing how to pass php values while calling js functions. It is working fine.

Comment: But it is showing in source even if not showing on page. As i have to collect values , so if it is completely removed then i can collect the values which are remaining and submit.
But as source shows them still there though on html page it gets removed.

Comment: @ashish: Like I answered, you don's need to pass any php values when calling JS functions.
the reason the source shows them there is because that's what the page looks like when it's loaded. Try the developer console, instead (F12 on most browsers)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass any ID's:

Try this:

```
function removeMore(element) {
    var tr = element.parentNode.parentNode; // Get the input's parent <tr>
    tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);          // Remove the <tr> from it's parent.
}
```

And for your buttons:

```
<input type="button" name="rem_but" id="some_ID" value="Remove this Row" onclick="removeMore(this)" />
```

In `removeMore`, `element` is the button itself. `element.parentNode`, is the `<td>` this button is in, and `element.parentNode.parentNode` is the `<tr>` it's in.

The advantage is that you don't have to add the `id` attributes to the buttons, if you're not using them elsewhere.

However, this code will break if you change the structure of your table. as it is right now, this works for:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" onclick="removeMore(this)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" onclick="removeMore(this)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you add a `<div>` around the `<input>`, for example, you'll have added another level of Dom Elements in between the `<tr>` and the `<input>`, meaning a extra `.parentNode`.

Comment: This is assuming that he doesn't arbitarily change the structure of his table at any time.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function removeMore(element_id)
{
    var elem = document.getElementById(element_id);
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    return false;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$row=5;
for($i=1; $i< $row; $i++)
{
    $img_id= "img_".$i;
    $cap_id= "cap_".$i;
    $row_id= "row_".$i*100;
    ?>
    <table>
    <tr id="<?php echo $row_id;?>">
        <td><input type="file" name="img[]" id="<?php echo $img_id;?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cap[]" id="<?php echo $cap_id;?>" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" name="rem_but" id="<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"   onclick="removeMore('<?php echo $row_id; ?>')" />
         </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <?php 
}   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that by using jQuery:

```
removeMore = function(id) {
    element_id = '#' + id + '00';
    $(element_id).remove();
}
```

Or without passing the id:

```
removeMore = function(element) {
    $(element).parent().remove();
}

<input type="button" onclick="removeMore(this)" value="">
```

Comment: There is absolutely no need to use jQuery basic DOM manipulation like this.

Comment: I'm sure that the described case is the only use case for the page that means that you've to make sure to provide the same functionality to a lot of different browsers, especially today as you've a high usage of client side scripting e.g. single-page applications. jQuery does maybe create some initial loading overhead, but it shortens the code a lot and makes it a lot easier to understand what happens inside the function for javascript newbies.

Comment: That might be so, but JavaScript newbies should start off learning JavaScript, not some library.
That'll get them thinking about efficiency a little, before just jumping into `$('#myElement')`. I mean, if I got a penny for every time I saw someone not cache jQuery objects...